# Not sure why my program outputs the last if statement by default

Tags: java

program is intended to take input as an integer and return a grade as well as a grade point. By default it keeps outputting the last if statement. Any help is appreciated as I am a complete beginner to this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gradePoint {
    int grade;
    String x;

public void getGrade() {
    int x = grade;

    if (x>90 && x<100) {
        System.out.println("A+ ; GradePoint 9");
    }else if(x>80 && x<89){
        System.out.println("A ; GradePoint 8");
    }else if(x>75 && x<79){
        System.out.println("B+ ; GradePoint 7");
        return;
    }else if (x>70 && x<74){
        System.out.println("B ; GradePoint 6");
    }else if (x>65 && x<69){
        System.out.println("C+ ; GradePoint 5");
    }else if (x>60 && x<64){
        System.out.println("C ; GradePoint 4");
    }else if (x>55 && x<59){
        System.out.println("D+ ; GradePoint 3");
    }else if (x>50 && x<54){
        System.out.println("D ; GradePoint 2");
    }else if (x>48 && x<49){
        System.out.println("E ; GradePoint 1");
    }else if (x<47){
        System.out.println("F ; GradePoint 0");
    }

}

public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println("enter grade");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    int grade = sc.nextInt();

    gradePoint g = new gradePoint();
    g.getGrade();

}
}
```

*output:*

```
 enter grade

   90

   F ; GradePoint 0
```

Comment: Point of style:  `getGrade` is misnamed.  A method called `getWhatever` should do exactly that: return (i.e., "get" for you) a _whatever_.  Your `getGrade` doesn't return anything, let alone a "grade": it just prints the "grade point" corresponding to some given "grade".  So it should be called exactly what it does: `printGradePointForGrade()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never pass the input grade into your `gradePoint` object.

Therefore the instance member `int grade;` remains 0 by default, so after `int x = grade;`, `x` is also 0.

You can use a constructor to initialize the `grade` variable:

```
public gradePoint (int grade)
{
    this.grade = grade;
}
```

and

```
gradePoint g = new gradePoint(grade);
g.getGrade();
```

Or you can pass the grade directly to your `getGrade()` method:

```
public void getGrade(int grade) {
    if (grade>90 && grade<100) {
        ...
}
```

and

```
gradePoint g = new gradePoint();
g.getGrade(grade);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program keeps printing `F ; GradePoint 0` because field `grade` of `gradePoint` class is zero. Variable `grade` inside `main` is local. It does not matter what its value is, because `grade` inside `getGrade` does not change.

You should make a few changes to your program to fix this problem:

- Rename the class to `GradePoint` to follow Java naming guidelines,
- Rename `getGrade` to `printGrade`, and make it a `static` method,
- Give `printGrade` a `grade` parameter of type `int`,
- Remove field `grade` from the class,
- Pass variable `grade` from `main` to `printGrade`.

After the modification your `main` should look like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println("enter grade");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int grade = sc.nextInt();
    printGrade(grade);
}
```

Comment: @JohnD You are welcome. If your problem is solved, please consider accepting one of the answers to indicate to other site visitors that you do not need additional help with this matter. This will also earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.